# spring evaluate expression (SpEL), how can I force it to not interprete some specials characteres

Tags: spring, special-characters, expression-evaluation

I'm using spring tool SpEL to evaluate some expressions.

The expression contain HTML/css programatically generated and some variables to evaluate.

```
<span style='font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';>TOTAL HT &nbsp; = totalItem  </span>
```

where totalItem is a member of an object Item;

Partial example :

```
Item item = new Item ("item", 1658);
String s = "<span style='font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';>TOTAL HT &nbsp; = totalItem </span>";
StandardEvaluationContext itemContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(item);
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(s);
s2 = exp.getValue(itemContext, String.class);
```

The problem is that SpEL interpret all " ' " and all " ; ".

So I'm looking for a way to force SpEl to interprete only the special caractere that I want to.

Comment: Escape the characters your do not want interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape those characters instead of interpreting them.

for `'`, escape them like `''`
And you can just leave `;` as it is.

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly for this example. I was looking for a way to escape the " ' " charactere. If I understand this, I can escape any charactere i want by putting it in simple quote, right ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to be taken care here:

You would need to pass `"'<span style=''font-total: ''Comic Sans MS'';>TOTAL HT &nbsp; = ' + #totalItem + '  </span>'"` to get the value.

The following code handles this in a dynamic way, you would need to take care of `split` part for special characters.

```
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();

        String input = "<span style='font-totalItemfamily: 'Comic Sans MS';>TOTAL HT &nbsp; = totalItem  </span>";
        String variableToEvaluate = "totalItem";
        String[] splits = input.split(variableToEvaluate);

        boolean appendedValue = false;
        StringBuilder expressionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            if (appendedValue) {
                expressionBuilder.append("#");
                expressionBuilder.append(variableToEvaluate);
                expressionBuilder.append(" + ");

            }
            expressionBuilder.append('\'');
            expressionBuilder.append(splits[i].replace("'", "''"));
            expressionBuilder.append('\'');
            appendedValue = true;
            if (i + 1 != splits.length) {
                expressionBuilder.append(" + ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(expressionBuilder.toString());
        context.setVariable(variableToEvaluate, 1);
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expressionBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println(exp.getValue(context, String.class));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this work for this example but I don't know the name of my variables in real case. Usually the String to evaluate come from database. The answer Jason Marsh give me fit better in my case.